# How to print an ascii table in python?

Tags: python, hex, decimal, ascii

I have a problem. I want to print a part of ASCII-Table. I mean it like this: I give first number - for Example 40 - and last number - let's say 100 and it print me number form 40 to 100. Including 40 and 100.
I got this so far:

```
def dectohex2(beg,end):
    print('{0:x}'.format(int(beg))," ", chr(beg))
    print('{0:x}'.format(int(end))," ", chr(end))
```

But I'm not sure what to put between those, to print other numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop over the range between `beg` and `end+1`:

```
def dectohex2(beg,end):
    for i in range(beg, end+1):
        print('{0:x}'.format(int(i))," ", chr(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this for other users who faced the same problem, you can use this script I wrote, it's an automated and cross-version way to get an ASCII ID or char from ID.

```
while True:
    number = 0
    try:
        char = raw_input("Character or ASCII ID: ")
    except:
        char = input("Character or ASCII ID: ")
    try:
        num = int(char)
        print("{0}: {1}".format(num, chr(num)))
    except:
        for i in range(1,250):
            number+=1
            if chr(i) == char:
                print(str(number)+": "+chr(i))
```